# Xcode can’t be installed on “Macintosh HD”

Tags: xcode

Xcode can’t be installed on “Macintosh HD” because macOS version 10.12.6 or later is required.
my macitosh version is 10.12 but when i searched for update it asks no updates are available

Answer (score 0):

An older Xcode version needs to be installed that is compatible with your macOS version. Older versions can be found here https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?q=xcode

You could install the latest version of Xcode which also has command line tools that support your version of macOS. For instance, if you have macOS 10.12 and there is a download titled `Command Line Tools (macOS 10.12) for Xcode 9.2` then you should be safe to install Xcode version 9.2